# Office Apps: No Network Connection: Please check your network settings and try again. [2604]

Tags: keychain, office-365

When I try and log in to my Office 365 apps with my corporate account on macOS Monterey 12.7.3 after changing my Active Directory password, I get the following error:

`No Network Connection: Please check your network settings and try again. [2604]`

- I do have a network connection. I can access SMB file shares.
- The Mac is joined to the Active Directory domain and I can log in with my *new* password.
- I entered my previous AD password at first login post-password-change to update my Keychain password as well.
- My IT group cannot support me per corporate policy because Macs aren't supported. They have helped me with small things out of kindness in the past (I.e. they joined my Mac to Active Directory).
- We use a Single Sign On solution which goes through VMWare Identity for all Office apps. I.e., Office asks for my email (Live account) and then displays, a message about redirecting me to my company login portal. That's when I see the dialog for VMWare Workspace ONE.
- If I enter a different username, it will prompt me for a password rather than displaying the network error.
- I've deleted every keychain item I can think of related to Microsoft, ADAL, etc.
- I've reset every component (short of completely uninstalling Office) using [Microsoft Office Reset](https://office-reset.com).

Based on this last point, I believe some piece of this SSO scheme (Office, Live, Kerberos, Keychain, VMware Workspace ONE, Oath, Microsoft OneAuth, ADAL, MSAL, MSAuth, etc.) is caching my old credentials. I'd like to find where those are cached and delete them so I can enter my new credentials.